# How to change the n-th value of a named range in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Here's a table about fruits:

[image]

These fruits are the names of named ranges in Column A, too. For example, if I type the following:

```
=INDEX(apple, 1, 1)
```

then the result is 1.

My question is: How can I change the n-th value of a named range in Excel VBA? I'd like to add a new value to the first element of named range 'apple', like:

```
Range("apple",1,1).Value = 2
```

How can I do that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In VBA: `Range("Apple").Offset(,1).value = 2`

Comment: Almost good, thanks! This code creates an extra column.

Comment: Is the range "Apple" a complete row, or just the cell that has that name?

Comment: So it sounds like your "Apple" named range isn't just the cell with the value "Apple" but the entire row on the table. @trincot's first solution should work then.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the range includes the cells to the right of the main cell, you can do:

```
Range("Apple")(2) = 123
```

`(1)` would reference the cell with "Apple", so you need to start with `(2)`. This notation is short for:

```
Range("Apple").Cells(2) = 123
```

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what the issue is with this answer?